# Store in array instead of printing

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to create an array after I put a for loop through an if argument that is read from a csv file. In this code below, I print the results. Instead of printing the results, I would like to store them in an array. How do I do this?

```
with open('_Stocks.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        if float(line['Rel Volume']) > 2.5:
            print(line['tckr'],line['Rel Volume'])
```

Comment: To create a new list: `results = []`. To add something to a list: `results.append(some object representing whatever you would have printed)`. Is that enough to get you going, or do you need help with something?

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
arr = []

with open('_Stocks.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        if float(line['Rel Volume']) > 2.5:
            arr.append(line['tckr'],line['Rel Volume'])
```

Comment: When I try this, I get an error message. TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given) ---- is there a way to use append with two arguments?

Comment: Right... You can either change it to `arr.extend([line['tckr'],line['Rel Volume']])`, or use 2 `arr.append`, one for `line['tckr']` and one for `line['Rel Volume']`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a nested list of lists (where each inner list contains two elements), do this:

```
my_list = []

with open('_Stocks.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        if float(line['Rel Volume']) > 2.5:
            my_list.append([line['tckr'],line['Rel Volume']])
```

If you want a flat (one-dimensional) list, do this:

```
my_list = []

with open('_Stocks.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        if float(line['Rel Volume']) > 2.5:
            my_list.extend([line['tckr'],line['Rel Volume']])
```

The only difference between the two examples is that one uses `extend()` and the other uses `append()`. Note that in each case, we pass a single list to whichever method we choose, by putting square brackets around `line['tckr'],line['Rel Volume']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to do this!  My example below will use a namedtuple, but you don't have to include that, it's not necessary.

```
from collections import namedtuple

CSVLine = namedtuple('CSVLine', ['tckr', 'Rel_Volume'])

with open('_Stocks.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    csvfilter = [ CSVLine(line['tckr'], line['Rel Volume']) for line in csv_reader if line['Rel Volume'] > 2.5]
```

Using the namedtuple, your array data will look something like this:

```
CSVLine(tckr='abcd', Rel_Volume=3.2), CSVLine(tckr='efgh', Rel_Volume=3.0), CSVLine(tckr='ijkl', Rel_Volume=4.2)
```

Without the namedtuple, it will simply look like this:

```
with open('_Stocks.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    csvfilter = [(line['tckr'], line['Rel Volume']) for line in csv_reader if line['Rel Volume'] > 2.5 ]
```

I used a tuple in both examples, because I assumed you would want to pair the data from each line together, for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas module is great for munging:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Mar 09 17:21:57 2018

@author: soyab
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#%%
## Load as a Pandas Dataframe ; Select rows based on Column logic
new_df = pd.read_csv('_Stocks.csv')
df_over_two_five = new_df.loc[new_df['Rel Volume'] > 2.5].copy()
df_over_two_five
```

It's good to post a chuck of your data with a question like this. Then I can make sure to catch silly errors.